# MySQL insert varchar value into int auto increment column

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, auto-increment

I noticed strange MySQL behaviour on projects staging server. Given:

```
create table test_table
(
    id   int auto_increment,
    name varchar(64) not null,
    constraint test_table_pk
        primary key (id)
);

insert into test_table (id, name)
VALUES (3, 'value 3');
insert into test_table (id, name)
VALUES (5, 'value 5');
insert into test_table (id, name)
VALUES ('value 6 id', 'value 6');

select *
from test_table;
```

Results:

```
mysql> select * from test_table;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  3 | value 3 |
|  5 | value 5 |
|  6 | value 6 |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

First two insert statements works fine as expected. What's the magic behind the third one? It works and it seems incorrect type value is replaced with auto increment value.
I'm trying to create docker version of the DB server. But I can't find what's config option to enable this behaviour. The third insert statement is rejected by docker DB instance with error message:

```
Incorrect Integer value: 'value 6 id' for column 'id'
```

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| version       | 5.7.27-30 |
+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

UPDATE

On Staging server:

```
show variables like '%sql_mode%';
```

Returns:

```
IGNORE_SPACE,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

My docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
 db:
    image: percona/percona-server:5.7.27
    volumes:
      -db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./db.env
    command:
      --sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:7.15.0
    command: migrate
    volumes:
      - ./../../sql/migrations:/flyway/sql
      - ./flyway/conf:/flyway/conf
    depends_on:
      -db
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: The docker DB is doing the right thing. What exactly is your point?

Comment: I want to create docker based DB instance that behaves the same way staging instance does. It's not about right/wrong behaviour.

Comment: strict_trans_table is a common sense setting. It should be enabled in all environments, not the other way round.

Comment: Agree. It's very strange behaviour in an example I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with sql_mode. You can check the sql_mode parameters of two database instances to find out the secrets.

`show variables like '%sql_mode%';`

Answer (score 2):

You have enabled `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` which causes invalid data values to be rejected, this should be removed from the list:

```
SET sql_mode='IGNORE_SPACE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zWjNJuM9)

Comment: That is correct but what does it do and why should it be removed?

Comment: The OP need invalid data to be inserted as well

Comment: Yes but what does it do?